# Apache access LAN server by domain name

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, lan

I have 2 domain name, 1 is "project2.servername.net" ,2 is "www.servername.net"
they both point to same project on local.

I want to set "project2.servername.net" to an other project which is already served by nginx on 192.168.0.9 , If I go to http://192.168.0.9:80 on browser, I will see the index page.

In the other hand, I hope the user which is access from "project2.servername.net" can be redirect to 192.168.0.9, not local project.

I tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername project2.servername.net
    ProxyPass /  http://192.168.0.9
    ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.0.9
    ProxyPreserveHost On  
    ProxyRequests Off
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername www.servername.net
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I go project2.servername.net , I got "Internal Server Error" by apache server.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solve by following settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ProxyPreserveHost  On
    ProxyPass          "/" "http://192.168.0.9/"
    ProxyPassReverse   "/" "https://192.168.0.9"
    Servername         project2.servername.net
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername www.servername.net
</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

I didn't activate the **proxy_http_module** module,  It's done by activate it.